# cakephp client/model validation for adding comment

Tags: jquery, cakephp

i am done coding for add comment using jquery ajax and its working fine.

I want to do validation while adding the comment. as of now its taking empty comment also.

what are the best ways to add validation for add comment

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [data validation chapter](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1143/Data-Validation) of the docs! Then if you are still stuck, post *your attempt* at solving the problem, then you will get an answer.

Comment: I am adding the comments using ajax. if i use the model validation how to show the error message

Comment: Well you should have said that. Make sure the input `.val() != '';` before submitting the form with ajax. Put the proper validation in the model also, as that will cover those without javascript.